# WordPress Localization error within return value

Tags: translation, localization

I have some code in my `functions.php` and when I try to make it localized, I always get it wrong.

Here is the code and I just want to localize the words "Read More":

```
return '<a href="'. get_permalink( $post->ID ) . 
    '"><span class="readmore">Read More</span></a>';
```

When I change "Read More" to `_e(` or `__(`, I get an error on that line. How do I make it work?

Here is the full function code:

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    global $post;
    return '<a href="'. get_permalink( $post->ID ) . 
        '"><span class="readmore">Read More</span></a>';
} 
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf()` can be used to break the string up so that the translatable string can be isolated from the HTML:

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return sprintf( '<a href="%1$s"><span class="readmore">%2$s</span></a>',
        get_permalink( get_the_ID() ),
        __( 'Read More', 'your-textdomain' )
    );
} 
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```